# Check last bit in a hex in SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a SQL entry that is of type hex (varbinary) and I want to do a SELECT COUNT for all the entries that have this hex value ending in 1.

I was thinking about using CONVERT to make my hex into a char and then use WHERE my_string LIKE "%1". The thing is that varchar is capped at 8000 chars, and my hex is longer than that.

What options do I have?

Comment: Type hex?  Do you mean `VARBINARY`?

Comment: There is no sql type of hex.

Comment: The binary representation needs to end in 1 or the hex representation? You are checking the last bit or last 4 bits?

Comment: it's varbinary. last bit should be 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Varbinary actually works with some string manipulation functions, most notably `substring`. So you can use eg.:

```
select substring(yourBinary, 1, 1);
```

To get the first byte of your binary column. To get the last bit then, you can use this:

```
select substring(yourBinary, len(yourBinary), 1) & 1;
```

This will give you zero if the bit is off, or one if it is on.

However, if you really only have to check at most the last 4-8 bytes, you can easily use the bitwise operators on the column directly:

```
select yourBinary & 1;
```

As a final note, this is going to be rather slow. So if you plan on doing this often, on large amounts of data, it might be better to simply create another `bit` column just for that, which you can index. If you're talking about at most a thousand rows or so, or if you don't care about speed, fire away :)

Answer (score 1):

Check last four bits = 0001

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN MyColumn % 16 IN (-15,1) THEN 1 END) FROM MyTable
```

Check last bit = 1

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN MyColumn % 2 IN (-1,1) THEN 1 END) FROM MyTable
```

If you are wondering why you have to check for negative moduli, try `SELECT 0x80000001 % 16`

Answer (score 0):

Try using this where

```
WHERE LEFT(my_string,1) = 1
```

Comment: it's not string, it's varbinary I'm after

Answer (score -1):

It it's text values ending in 1 then you want the Right as opposed to the Left

```
WHERE RIGHT(my_string,1) = 1
```